# How do I create a public-key/private-key pair and safely store them into a key container?

Tags: c#, security, cryptography

I have been trying to do some simple cryptography practice, but I am stumped. I have thus far been able to generate a pair of public and private keys, but I haven't figured out how to safely store them or make them persist beyond a single session. In my research, I've heard of this thing called a "key container" that allows these keys to (safely) persist beyond a single session and be retrieved at a later time.

Unfortunately, cryptography is complicated, so every time I think I've figured something out, it gives me five more questions that have to be answered before I can understand what I'm doing. By this point, my head is swimming with all this information, and I'm having quite a bit of trouble making sense of it all. So...

I would like to see a code example that creates a public-key/private-key pair, saves them in a key container, and then retrieves them. If possible, I would also like to see some code that retrieves a public key and a private key from a key container that is assumed to already exist. For constraints, assume that Visual Studios C# is being used in a .NET framework, on a Windows 10 OS.

I'd prefer to see this with RSA encryption, unless there is a safer way to do this.

I am almost certain that this is more or less a duplicate question, but if so, then I haven't found the original yet.

Comment: Please take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-store-asymmetric-keys-in-a-key-container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowed from [a corefx test](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/0531d814e6e7ed1286f635d9d2f216d0bb2f0c66/src/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/tests/CertificateCreation/PrivateKeyAssociationTests.cs#L180-L189) (and other code in the same file):

```
// Ideally you use a name that won't ever be used by someone else.
// Certificate import names its keys GUIDs, but then has to remember what they were.
const string KeyName = "SomePersistedKey";
const int Size = 2048; // Or whatever.
```

CNG:

```
CngKey key = null;

try
{
    key = CngKey.Open(KeyName);
}
catch (CryptographicException)
{
    // This is only in the catch block to avoid a scrollbar.
    CngKeyCreationParameters creationParameters = new CngKeyCreationParameters()
    {
        ExportPolicy = CngExportPolicies.None, // Or whatever.
        Provider = CngProvider.MicrosoftSoftwareKeyStorageProvider,
        KeyCreationOptions = CngKeyCreationOptions.OverwriteExistingKey,
        Parameters =
        {
            new CngProperty("Length", BitConverter.GetBytes(Size), CngPropertyOptions.None),
        }
    };

    cngKey = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.Rsa, KeyName, creationParameters);
}

using (cngKey)
using (RSA rsa = new RSACng(cngKey))
{
    // Tada.
}
```

Or, if you need to stick with CAPI (hopefully not):

```
const int PROV_RSA_AES = 24;

CspParameters cspParameters = new CspParameters(PROV_RSA_AES)
{
    KeyNumber = (int)KeyNumber.Exchange,
    KeyContainerName = KeyName,
    Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseNonExportableKey, // Or whatever.
};

// This constructor is open-or-create since flags didn't asset ExistingOnly.
using (RSA rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(Size, cspParameters))
{
    // tada.  Use CNG instead, if you can.
}
```

Comment: Alright, I want to make sure I understand this...
So, CngKey.Open("keyName") opens a preexisting object named "keyName", but I'm not sure what happens if keyName doesn't already exist. Does it throw an error or try to create a new key?

The catch statement appears to create a new key named KeyName, defining necessary parameters and such. If I'm reading it correctly, it allows the dev to set the CngExportPolicies, defines where the key will be stored, replaces any existing key with that name (I'm assuming "just in case"), and sets important details about the key. 

Is that correct so far?

Comment: Yep. CngKey.Open throws if it doesn't exist. There's also CngKey.Exists, if you prefer exception-free.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! So that means that the exception causes the key to be created if it doesn't already exist, guaranteeing that there is a persistent key to be used, whether it previously existed or not. Thank you!